# exctract substring from a large string under certain conditions in painless

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

In painless I would like to create a script which reads a keyword field called ***'objldn'*** and extracts only five consecutive characters sometimes present in a precise position. Infact, in the keyword field ***'objldn'*** there are a large variety of long strings among which there are some of them with a third underscore. After the third underscore, if it is present, I can fetch the consecutive 5 chars.
Whith the following lines of code I implement what I want:

```
def LU = doc['objldn'].value.splitOnToken('_');
return LU[3].substring(0, 5);
```

---

But the system returnes an error message **"out of bounds"**:

> Request error: array_index_out_of_bounds_exception, Index 3 out of
> bounds for length 3 in "def LU =
> doc['objldn'].value.splitOnToken('_'); ..." (Painless script)
>
> error executing runtime field or scripted field on index pattern
> return LU[3].substring(0, 5);
> ^---- HERE

may be it is due to the fact that many strings do not have the third underscore or do not even have one and therefore I need to implement firstly a **IF** statement which evaluates if a third underscore is in the string and only if it is present it proceeds to execute **splitOnToken()**... but I am not able to do it correctly. Can you help me to add the **IF** statement in the script please?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply checking the length of the `LU` array?

```
def LU = doc['objldn'].value.splitOnToken('_');
return LU.length >= 4 ? LU[3].substring(0, 5) : null;
```

Comment: yes, I hadn't thought about it. It's clear your solution anf it works perfectly! Thank you Val